# How can I ensure correct filtering of a detail table from a summary table?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

In this production data the Total Quantity processed through the machines is in table **WeekProd** and the number of parts scrapped is stored in table **WeekScrap**. There can be more than one scrap reason and quantity for each production line and they are summed using a measure.

The two tables are filtered in common by the calendar week number, the machine lookup and the shift lookup. Using 2 visuals shows that this filtering is working as expected:

[image: Image 1]

However, when I place the **Sum Scrap Qty** measure onto the **WeekProd** visual it show the scrap qty on every row, although the total figure of 34 ends up correct.

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Hi, add the code of the measure, please.

Comment: Sum Scrap Qty = SUM(WeekScrap[Scrap Qty])

Comment: I'm using this same measure on both visuals.

Comment: It looks like there is no relationship between two tables

Comment: So that fact that they have a common filter context in not enough, I actually need to build a direct relationship between the tables? They are currently both being filtered by Calendar[Week], Machine[MachineLkup] and Shift[ShiftLkup] and I assumed that this filter context would automatically apply between the tables.

Comment: There is a filter context applied from calendar table. Your second visual displays only one row for week 14. The engine doesn't know in what row it is. So it repeats the 34 for each row. I mean it doesn't see the shiftlkup and machinelkup at all. Read more about filter and row context, and context transition as well. You can change that behavior via calculate or by creating the bridge table.

Comment: Thanks. I've got it working by building the bridge table using a compound key to link the two tables. I will read up more about filter and row context so that I can understand how to do the same with calculate.